# passing variables with $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, parameter-passing

I have two checkboxes with some values like this:

```
<label for="hotel_boutique"><input id="hotel_boutique" name="hotel_boutique" value="test" type=checkbox />test</label><br />
```

3

and I get these values with an Ajax call like this:

```
<script>
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){

if (jQuery('input#hotel_boutique').is(':checked')) {
    var hotel_boutique = jQuery("#hotel_boutique").map(function () {return this.value;}).get();
}else{
    var hotel_boutique = 'NULL';
    }
if (jQuery('input#hotel_stars').is(':checked')) {
    var hotel_stars = jQuery("#hotel_stars").map(function () {return this.value;}).get();
}else{
    var hotel_stars = 'NULL';
    }

var data = 'hotel_boutique="'+hotel_boutique+'"&hotel_stars="'+hotel_stars+'"';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "processAjax.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        jQuery("#loading").show();
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        jQuery("#content").html('');
        jQuery("#content").append(data);
        jQuery("#loading").hide();
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Now when I echo the variables in the server side (PHP) it displays:

```
"test"
```

Who and why are the `"` added? And how can I remove them?

I have already tried the PHP function `preg_replace` and other stuff.

please need your help...

Answer (score 5):

You can use an object instead of string like

```
var data = {
    hotel_boutique: hotel_boutique,
    hotel_stars: hotel_stars
};
```

The problem is the `"` in the data string, you can also try

```
var data = 'hotel_boutique='+hotel_boutique+'&hotel_stars='+hotel_stars;
```

---

The overall code can be simplified as

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    var data = {
        hotel_boutique: $('#hotel_boutique:checked').val()||'NULL',
        hotel_stars: $('#hotel_stars:checked').val()||'NULL'
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "processAjax.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery("#loading").show();
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            jQuery("#content").html(data);
            jQuery("#loading").hide();
        },
        error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, the only really 'right' answer, since the object notation isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass key-value pair:

```
data: {hotel_boutique: hotel_boutique,hotel_stars: hotel_stars},
```

In this call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    data: data,      // change here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "processAjax.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        hotel_boutique: hotel_boutique,
        hotel_stars : hotel_stars
     },
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        jQuery("#loading").show();
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        jQuery("#content").html('');
        jQuery("#content").append(data);
        jQuery("#loading").hide();
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }

});
```